# DLog macro, "autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking" errors in ios 4.3

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

[It's not DLog, it was a separate thread. See edits/comments below]

XCode 4.3
I'm using the common preprocessor macro for debug logging:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#   define DLog(fmt, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " fmt), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__); 
#else
#   define DLog(...)
#endif
```

Compiles/works fine under iOS 5.0, but when I run it under iOS 4.3 I get a ton of "autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking" errors whenever DLog is executed. Tried rebooting, no help.

Am I haunted, or is there a solution?  TIA.

**[edit 1]**

Forgot to mention it's an ARC project. The only autorelease pool is the default in main.m:

```
@autoreleasepool {
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    return retVal;
}
```

There's nothing special about any of my DLog use, in fact the errors trigger upon app start when I simply put

```
DLog(@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
```

**[edit 2]**

Sorry, it's not DLog causing the issue. Here's the first line that will cause it for me:

```
BOOL customDates = [[defaults objectForKey:@"custom_dates"] boolValue];
```

Console reports:

> *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x15cca20 of class NSCFBoolean autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

I'm still confused by all these leak messages because I thought we didn't need to worry about autorelease with ARC. So what is its problem?

Comment: That would indicate the code is running with no autoreleasepool in place. Any chance you can show a code block where you use `DLog` that would match that description? Also, do you use `@autoreleasepool` blocks anywhere in your code?

Comment: Do you use threads anywhere in your project? Or possibly a `__attribute__((constructor))` function?

Comment: No threads. Fairly simple project. This has seemingly come out of nowhere. I am completing the updating of a non-ARC iOS 4 iPhone app to ARC and iOS 5 (though no iOS 5-specific code is being used).

Comment: Does the message also say "break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug"?

Comment: Not Dlog but still getting the problem, see edits to original post. Sorry.

Comment: Gah! I forgot that I *do* have a thread: MBProgressHUD works by executing a thread in the background while updating a progress HUD. So if I wrap the entire code that executes with @autorelease the issue goes away.

Why does this only occur in iOS 4.3?

Comment: you may want to refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770213/arc-memory-leaks