# ARC and memory Issue

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, nsoperation

ARC is enabled in my project,I found in a post of this site that  Cocoa creates an autorelease pool for you on the main thread, but doesn't do anything for you on background threads. If you're going to kick something off onto a background thread without using NSOperation or something, you'll want to wrap that thread in an @autoreleasepool [ARC memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770213/arc-memory-leaks,so) I modified my code,still having memory leak issue.Please help. 
             [image]

According to you Bryan Chen I have edited[image]

Now getting issue here
 [image]

[image]

[image]

Next modification
[image]

Comment: What profile in Instruments are you using to get these results?

Comment: Instruments doesn't have a "Provisioning" profile. When you Build for Profiling, and another app opens up, what do you select from the sheet that appears?

Comment: If you look at the list of objects, what does it say is leaking? That's more likely to help than random screenshots of code.

Answer (score 0):

put `@autoreleasepool` in your first `dispatch_async` (jsonParsingQueue)

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you `dispatch_async` a block to the main queue, that block will be executed on the main thread and therefore already has an autorelease pool. Therefore the autorelease pool in your existing code is unnecessary where it is, and should be moved such that it encloses the entire contents of the block being dispatched to the `jsonParsingQueue`.

EDIT: Actually, *all* GCD queues **do** have autorelease pools automatically, so although it can be useful to create an additional pool to have better control over memory use, it should not cause a leak if you don't. I think you might have another issue.

See here for reference: [Do you need to create an NSAutoreleasePool within a block in GCD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141123/do-you-need-to-create-an-nsautoreleasepool-within-a-block-in-gcd)

Comment: Edited according to you still having issues

Comment: Your @autoreleasepool is still not quite in the right spot. It should enclose the contents of the block being dispatched to the jsonParsingQueue. That is, it should start after the line that looks like `dispatch_async(jsonParsingQueue, ^{` and end on the line after the `});` that closes the inner dispatch_async.